# SAGA Majority Filter - what is radius?

Tags: qgis, filter, radius

In QGIS, Saga's majority filter has only a few parameters: the raster, search cell type, and the radius. I thought it uses a kernel or moving window, so my question is what does the radius refer to? I saw on some tutorial that it corresponds to a 5x5 search window, How could that be?

Comment: A kernel radius is the distance in pixels from the outside edge of the center pixel to the edge of the kernel. In the case of a 5*5 kernel (window), the radius is 2.

Comment: Ah. Got it. Thank you.